# Google Maps API V2 - always get authentication error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I found lots of questions regarding this - and I am almost ashamed to ask it myself.

But no matter how hard I try, I simple *do not get the Maps API running* at all!

Not with the demo project, com.example.mapdemo, not with my own project.

I definitely have my debug.keystore SHA1 fingerprint registered, now for both my app and com.example - I also tried the browser API key where everybody says that would work, too.

BUT NO.

I always get:

```
06-16 11:21:29.860: E/Google Maps Android API(2382): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
```

I am getting REALLY, REALLY mad at this. How is it possible to NOT completely and thoroughly describe this matter so that people that are otherwise able to program Android apps, can follow and succeed??

HOW?

Could anybody please tell me what else could be wrong?

Add-on: I set up everything exactly according to the specs, got my key from my debug.keystore, tried it with com.example for the maps demo, with my own package for my app. Does not work.
Plus: that silly empty window. How on earth is that gonna work... :-(

Comment: Oups. Sorry for the typo... :-)

Comment: I have faced same issue today.already working map didn't display in my app and I worried.I have figured it out by changing my machine's current SHA to developer site for map as my SHA got changed(may be it got changes because I have updated my Android Studio and SHA relies on debug.keystore) and I got my issue resolved.

Comment: Are you still getting the error you mentioned in your question as this question is asked a long time ago?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming

- you are trying this on a device that has access to Google Play Services
- you have linked your project with the Google Play Services library
- you have setup the necessary permissions like this:

snippet from manifest:

```
<!-- Specify the correct minSDK and targetSDK versions. -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- Google Maps related permissions -->
<permission
    android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network connectivity permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Access Google based webservices -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

- you have setup the map key like this :

[image]

- you have put the meta-data tag **inside** the application tag

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyA_u1faIXRhx_Q7NafFbrhQJEerl6UUbPY" />
  ```
- you made sure that you are building the APK with the correct keystore (corresponding to the one defined in the API console).
- you removed and redeployed your application completely after checking / updating these steps you should be good to go.

From my experience I was able to follow the instructions on [Google Maps Android API v2 Getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start), but I do recall having to **completely undeploy and redeploy the app** again after playing around with the API keys / permissions.

On what device are you running ?

Comment: Yes, all your assumptions are correct. I try it on my HTC One. Don't really know what Google wants and how on earth that should work. Not even the maps demo app works, and there I first tried the "browser" key that some people were talking about and then I tried my own key. I took it from debug.keystore, deployed the app from Eclipse. I removed it completely several times. No chance. It simply does not work. I would like to know why Google does something SO WEIRD! The message does not help at ALL.

Comment: I've been fighting with this for days and did the tutorial several times.  What fixed it for me was simply uninstalling the app from my phone and then installing it again.  The look on my face then... :)

Comment: @trevor-e I also noticed that sometimes re-installing the app was required (as noted in my answer). It was as if sometimes an old or invalid api key was cached and a simple deploy of the app didn't refresh it. Uninstalling and re-installing the app usually helps.

Comment: I had the same thing as ddewaele. Everything was correct but I had to go into my phone's application manager to remove the existing install first.

Answer (score 2):

I am also having the same issue and know I kinda know what causes the problem ( not the solution to it though -yet- )

Try to run your app of other phone than your HTC One. Because I have the issue with my HTC One but when I run it on my S3, it runs perfectly.

Try and let me know please

**EDIT**

I solved it. But not sure what was the exact solution but here what I did as steps: 
1- I displayed the developers options in the phone settings use the 7 times clicks in 4.2 OS
2- Allowed Mock Location
3- Selected my app in the "select debug app"
4- uninstalled my app
5- re-installed it 
6- run it and waited for 30 seconds then the maps showed

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem , then i found out that i had made a simple mistake please verify whether you have turned on "Google Maps Android API v2" in services catagory of google api console . I had turned on the wrong one it never worked for me , but now it works,
hope this helps.
https://code.google.com/apis/console

Answer (score 2):

Even I was facing the same issue for days. I simply uninstalled the app from settings, reinstalled it and magically it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had got same issue. After checking 20th time the steps from ddewaele's answer, turning on the Maps V2 android in Google's API console, I have restarted my phone, waited ~15s for data to download and all works like a charm. Uninstalling application was not enough to get it working. Just leaving info for other map using devs on the edge.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem i spent two weeks to get a solution at last i got it.
    just remove key from res/values/google_maps_api.c and repalace it by new key
    follow below steps you will get a new key.

```
1> Find SHA1 by Using that command in command prompt:

keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

2> Get Package name from android manifest and use finger print of SHA1 for create an new api key 


3> copy created key and past it in res/values/google_maps_api.xml and also past in android manifest 

<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">Paste Here New Api</string>
</resources>

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="Paste Key Here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread but it was edited few months ago, and i just run into the same problem. Since the cause of my version of the problem was a bit different i'll add it here. I had checked that all the previously cited conditions where true but it was still giving the same error.

After some hours of randomly trying stuff i finally found out that the xml string translation manager of Android Studio had created a new string with the same identifier of the google api key (which is by default stored in a different xml file from the other strings). This new string resource was indeed empty and conficlting with the true key. It was sufficient to delete it to solve the problem.