# Google Maps not working Android 2.2.2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm really hoping someone can help me.  I'm using google maps in an application.  I am working on someone elses code so I'm not sure how to fix this problem.  The code checks to see if textureview is supported, if it is use it else use surface view.  The maps work perfectly with newer devices, however, when testing it on a htc desire 2.2.2, there are no maps displayed.  It actually says in the logcat authentication error, I'm not sure how this is possible because there isn't any authentication error when running on newer devices.

The code used is from this library

https://github.com/NyxDigital/NiceSupportMapFragment/blob/master/src/com/NYXDigital/NiceSupportMapFragment.java

In the services section of the Google API's console Google Maps Android API v2 only is set on.

The authentication error I think is unusual as there isn't an issue with the newer devices.

If anyone has come across this before I'd appreciate it you could offer some advice

**EDIT ---- THIS PHONE IS RUNNING 2.2.2**

Comment: upon further inspection of my logcat, it says autorization error:  please ensure the key and the fingerprint certificate match those in the api console.  When I check, the key matches but the finger print doesn't.  This is strange and the key was generated with use of the fingerprint in the api console.  Plus there's no authorization error with the newer phones...does this make any sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate issue of some other API V2 authentication error questions questions please see:

[Android Google Maps V2 authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679317/android-google-maps-v2-authentication-error)

and

[Google Maps API V2 - always get authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131878/google-maps-api-v2-always-get-authentication-error)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions, this isn't a duplicate, I've been through stack overflow.  I don't know what the issue is.  Would you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might come across this issue in future...
This line

```
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_888);
```

of the git hub library code was preventing the map from being displayed, it wasn't anything to do with authorization.  The authorization issue was that I wasn't using the correct debug key, but when I had sorted this issue, the maps not displaying was still causing hassle.

So after much debugging and commenting of code, I discovered that the above line is the culprit.  So I added a simple check and it's sorted

Comment: What was your simple check ?